# How to make the scrollbar of QScrollArea transparent?

Tags: qt, user-interface

As you can see , there're white triangles within the red rectangle. I want to make the scrollbar's background of QScollArea transparent.
I have tried several stylesheets:

1. `QScrollBar::up-arrow {background-color:transparent}`
2. `QScrollBar {background-color:transparent}`
3. `QScrollArea {background-color:transparent}`

But none of them works.
How can I do that?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using an image for the up arrow with a transparent background?